# python re.compile(“regex”).search returns span(0, 0) match=“”

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I’ve been using `re` library in python for a while.
However, there is something I don’t understand.

```py
pattern = re.compile('[.]')
result = pattern.search('abcde')
print(result)
```

The above returns:  `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>`

while:

```py
pattern = re.compile('.')
result = pattern.search('abcde')
print(result)
```

This returns: `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>`

**Q1:** What is the difference between searching for `'[.]'` and `'.'` in python?

**Q2:** I understand that searching `'a'` in `'abcd'` returns `'span=(0, 1)'`. But what does `'span=(0, 0)'` actually mean?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but maybe '[.]' is equivalent to '\.', i.e. matches the period character. I assume span(0,1) means the match was found at position 0, length 1 whereas span(0,0) means no match, because there is no period in the string.

Comment: To Nicholas Hunter: You are right. Since I put “.” In [ ], it becomes literally a “.” like “\.”. Thank you!

Comment: Jerome Richard, thanks for editing! Im new to StackOverFlow, I will keep your fixes in mind!

Answer (score 2):

What version of Python are you on? I'm on 3.7 and the first returns `None` for me.

When you do `[]`, you're specifying that you want to match characters in the set. `.` is no longer a wildcard for you and it's trying to match an actual period in the string.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question at a very first time. I was using Pythonista ios app! I think your right, and it was a bug in the app!

Answer (score 2):

> **Q1:** What is the difference between searching for `'[.]'` and `'.'` in python?

Answer: the difference is how regex works rather than python itself.

As you probably know `.` (dot) is a regex metachar used to match any one character and square brackets `[]` is used to match multiple different characters in one particular position. Using a dot inside brackets ie `[.]` will match the character `.` literally and since it doesn't exists in the string `abcde` in the first example you don't get a match.

> **Q2:** I understand that searching `'a'` in `'abcd'` returns `'span=(0, 1)'`. But what does `'span=(0, 0)'` actually mean?

Answer: `span()` returns the length of a possible match.

Since you didn't get any match in the first example the length is set to zero hence `span=(0, 0), match=''` where `match` is an empty string.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I think your right!